# Pip failure when installing kivy

Tags: python, installation, pip, kivy

I am getting the error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-LfR5R_/kivy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-m4sDnl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-LfR5R_/kivy` when trying to install kivy on Mac OS X Yosemite
```

This is a new install with Xcode but I don't understand what I am missing,
any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using `sudo` or not?

Comment: Yes I am in `sudo su -` mode but I have also tried running it as sudo at one time Ex `sudo pip install kivy`

Comment: What's the output of `xcode-select -p`?

Comment: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: The pip version you are using?

Comment: `pip 6.1.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)`

Comment: I tried install kivy myself. It seems to need `Cython`. Did you have it installed?

Comment: Yep cython 2.1 `Cython version 0.21`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76402/discussion-between-ondeckshooting-and-skyline75489).